# SSTable loading concurrent exception

Tags: cassandra, nosql, concurrency, exception

While loading sstables through SSTableLoader command, I am frequently facing this issue.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getWhenDone(AbstractFuture.java:239)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:246)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:109)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:243)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:524)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.initiatorCompleteOrWait(StreamSession.java:920)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.complete(StreamSession.java:874)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:614)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamDeserializingTask.java:76)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getWhenDone(AbstractFuture.java:239)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:246)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:109)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:243)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:205)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:524)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.initiatorCompleteOrWait(StreamSession.java:920)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.complete(StreamSession.java:874)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:614)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamDeserializingTask.run(StreamDeserializingTask.java:76)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried to search in the DataStax site but unable to rectify the issue. In fact, I am not running other process ids. I have also allocated heap space as 100 GB. I am not able to find the right solution for this problem and been trying for the past 1 week. Is there any way, we can debug the issue

Comment: Please post additional details like what version of OSS C* version you're using and the full command you executed when getting this exception. Also, from where are you getting these SSTables and loading them into your C* cluster?

Comment: MAX_HEAP_SIZE="100G" sstableloader -d nodeid is the command.

The sstable is taken as a snapshot from old cluster which is having version 3.1 and migrationg to new version 4.1. of cluster size of 5.

Comment: There is actually an easier path to [perform an in-place upgrade of this existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/docs/guides/upgrade/overview.html) to your desired version. Also, [C* never had a version of `3.1`](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) so is it `3.11.x` by chance?

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check it. Yes. It is 3.11.x version only.